# Programmatically access the notebook job # in Databricks Pyspark in a sub-notebook

Tags: databricks

I am running multiple notebooks in parallel from one parent notebook using concurrent.futures (see snippet below). I would like to programmatically access the notebook job id of the notebooks I am running so I can track down which one failed. I could either access the job id inside the child notebook or at the parent level.

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
import json
 
# used to carry notebook data
@dataclass
class Notebook:
  path: str
  timeout: int
  parameters: dict = None
  retry: int = 0
  enabled:bool = True
  # add the notebook name to parameters using the path and return
  def getParameters(self):
     
    if not self.parameters:
      self.parameters = dict()
       
    params = self.parameters
    params["notebook"] = self.path
    return params

"""
Execute a notebook with retries. If the notebook throws an error on the last retry, raise that error.
"""
def executeNotebook(notebook:Notebook):
  print(f"Executing notebook {notebook.path} - {notebook.parameters['name']}")
  while notebook.retry >= 0:
    try:
      return dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.getParameters())
    except Exception as e: 
      if notebook.retry < 1:
        failed = json.dumps({
            "status" : "failed",
            "error" : str(e),
            "notebook" : notebook.path,
            "parameters": notebook.getParameters()
        })
        return failed
      print(f"Retrying notebook {notebook.path} - {notebook.parameters['name']}")
      notebook.retry -= 1

"""
Parallel execute a list of notebooks
"""
def executeNotebooks(notebooks:List[Notebook], maxParallel:int):
  print(f"Executing {len(notebooks)} notebooks with a maxParallel of {maxParallel} ")
  promises = []
  with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=maxParallel) as executor:
    for notebook in notebooks:
      if notebook.enabled:
        promises.append(executor.submit(executeNotebook, notebook))
  done, not_done = futures.wait(promises, return_when=futures.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
  for future in done:
    result = future.result()
    if result:
      yield json.loads(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

finding the `job_id` based on the notebook little hard. As work around, we can get the all `job_id` in workspace level based on the `/list` , iterate the `job_id` with condition of notebook path based on the `/get`. You can tweak the blow code based on your use case.

Getting available job's `job_id` :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
import base64
import requests
import json

databricks_instance ="https://databricksinstance"

url_list = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.1/jobs/list"

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers).json()
print(response)
print(response['job_id'])
print(response['start_time'])
print(response['end_time'])
```

Getting the job details based on the `job_id`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
import base64
import requests
import json

databricks_instance ="https://databricksinstance"

url_list = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.1/jobs/get?job_id=11292817"

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers).json()
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the job_id inside of the nested notebook, the difficulty is getting this value *out* of the nested notebook to the caller.  One option is to return this value as the output of the notebook upon completion, however this only gets us the value *if the notebook successfully completes.*  If the notebook encounters an error and exits early you will not get a return value (and this is perhaps when you're most interested in getting the job_id...)

To remedy this, the first action in the nested notebook should be to get and store the job_id, then proceed with executing the rest of the notebook.  Provide a unique ID to the nested notebook when executing it, create a temporary view with that name that contains the job_id, then read that temporary view in the caller after the nested notebook(s) complete.

For example, firing off the nested notebook:

```
// Some combination of unique information for the notebook, such as parameters you're passing in
// Or just generate a guid
var notebookId = createNotebookId()
dbutils.notebook.run("/nestedNotebook", 4800, Map("NestedNotebookId" -> notebookId)
```

In the nested notebook get the job_id (and any other information you wish to pass back out) and store it as a temporary view

```
var notebookTags = dbutils.notebook.getContext.tags
var jobId = 0
if (notebookTags.contains("jobId")) {
    jobId = notebookTags("jobId").toInt
}

val nestedNotebookDF = Seq((jobId, ...)).toDF("jobId", ...)
nestedNotebookDF.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(nestedNotebookId)
```

Now back in your caller you can read from that temporary view after the nested notebook has run to get the job_id

```
val global_temp_db = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.globalTempDatabase")
val nestedJobId = spark.table(s"$global_temp_db.$notebookId").select("jobId").first.getInt(0)
```

This same principal applies whether you're running one nested notebook, or an array of hundreds/thousands in parallel.